# WIF has IsSessionMode = true but still produces chunked cookies on occasion

Tags: cookies, wif

I've got an unusual problem with WIF. I have to use WIF 3.5 because of compatibility with .Net 4.0.

Following the advice from Vittorio Bertocci here http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2010/05/26/your-fedauth-cookies-on-a-diet-issessionmode-true/  We have set IsSessionMode = true in WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SecurityTokenValidated, and most of the time it is working perfectly - we are getting small FedAuth tokens which are pointers to our token in our memory cache.

However, periodically we are getting chunked FedAuth cookies which contain the full token information.

There is no obvious place in our code where we have an alternative code path.

I can't find any other examples of this particular inconsistency on Stack Overflow, or in any blogs about WIF on the wider internet, so I'm throwing this question out here in case anyone else has seen this problem and resolved it.

Meanwhile we are going to try setting up so that we can debug through the WIF code if we can make the problem occur reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've found out the problem - IsSessionMode was being set in the wrong place, it should have been on SessionSecurityTokenCreated. It appears that it was being set per-instance rather than on init which meant that in some circumstances it had the default value of true.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be sharing another relying party's cookie? One which is not using session? Try explicitly naming each RP's cookie -each one differently.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, turned out to be a silly problem in the end.